# How to disable user unsetting chat history via Google Talk

Tags: g-suite, instant-messaging

We are using Google Apps standard edition with 50 users and as an administrator I would like all users (mostly teenage students) chat information / history to be stored in their chats folder in their inbox.

Is there a way for preventing the user from unsetting this as an administrator so that they are not able to disable and use don't Save Chat history.

Comment: Don't forget that Google Talk is just XMPP. Those who don't want history can use a client that supports encryption.

Comment: Actually, I didn't want my users to unset chat history we would like to capture them. Looks like it is an unresolved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, It doesnt look like it is possible.

Google apps does have a marketplace for addon apps. There is an administration section of apps that give admins more control/functionality. You might find an app to prevent the chat log disable:

- http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?categoryId=1&orderBy=rating

As you may already know a standard edition account comes with no support for issues other than: login issues, abuse and billing.

If you upgrade to premier ($50/user per year -$2500 anually for 50 users) you could contact google directly about the issue.

- Source: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=contacting_support.html

The google apps help forum is free and may produce a more knowlegable/favorable answer:

- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps?hl=en

Comment: anything to provide some additional control for the administrator would be helpful

Comment: More people who want what you do (still no solution): http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=5e8d700ecfb5e60d&hl=en